# Why am I being blocked from using the Google Analytics Add-on In Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics

I'm trying to add the Google Analytics Add-on from within a Google Sheet. However, I'm being blocked. Here are the steps I'm taking:

1. Click "Extensions",
2. Hover over "Add-Ons",
3. Click "Get Add-On"
4. *The Add-Ons modal appears*
5. Search Google Analytics
6. Click on the Google Analytics search result
7. Click "Install"
8. Click "Continue"
9. *A SSO GMail modal pops up*
10. I click on my email
11. Then I get a "This App is Blocked" error message

["This App is Blocked" error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khvzy.png)

What do I do? Has anyone fixed this? Thanks so much!

Comment: [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on) To ask a question about the add-on or to report a bug, post a message to the [google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on).